# Prevent Updating TextField (Riverpod)

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Using Riverpod
In the below code.
I don't want the textField value to be updated through rebuilds
Just I want to get the value from the state at the first time, and I need to keep listening to the state to update other things.

If the user updated the field then the widget rebuilt, I need to keep the user's value without refresh.

```
class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final state = ref.watch(myStateProvider);
    return TextFormField(
      controller: TextEditingController(text: state.firstName.value),
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'First Name', errorText: state.firstName.errorMessage),
    );
  }
}
```

**Without using `onChange`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ConsumerStatefulWidget`:

```dart
class Example extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();

}

class _ExampleState extends ConsumerState<Example> {
  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState()
    _textEditingController.text = ref.read(myStateProvider).firstName.value;
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final state = ref.watch(myStateProvider);
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _textEditingController,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'First Name', errorText: state.firstName.errorMessage),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be reset at every build. It is only setting the value of the `TextEditingController` in the `initState`. Then, in every build, it is reusing the `TextEditingController` that is not updated by your model.